# How do you create UIBarButtonItems with a radio interface?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIToolbar that needs three buttons in a radio style, meaning that of the three, only one button can be pushed at a time.  The documentation makes reference to the possibility of setting up radio UIBarButtonItems in the class reference definition of the width property:

> If this property value is positive,
>   the width of the combined image and
>   title are fixed. If the value is 0.0
>   or negative, the item sets the width
>   of the combined image and title to
>   fit. **This property is ignored if the
>   style uses radio mode.** The default
>   value is 0.0.

However, I did a find for "radio" in the UIKit Framework Reference and I can't find any mention of UIBarButtonItems in radio style.  I know that I could alternatively use a TabBar for a radio interface, but a TabBar doesn't quite match the purpose of my UI (normal buttons + radio buttons).  I see that the Calendar App uses UIBarButtonItems in a radio style (List, Day, Month), so it seems like this should be somewhere in the API and approved by the HIG.  Is this hiding somewhere or would I have to create UIBarButtonItems with custom views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A UISegmentedControl is what you want. It's kind of hiding in Interface Builder, as it's a different style outside of a toolbar.

The normal style:

[image: normal segmented control]

The same thing in a toolbar:

[image: bar segmented control]

You have two options for its behavior: a momentary highlight when tapped, or a radio-style behavior, which is what you want. You can set this with the "Momentary" checkbox in the Attributes inspector:

[image: segmented control attributes]

Comment: Oohhhh, I didn't know you could add segmented controls into toolbars.  I thought only UIBarButtonItems were allowed.  Oops!  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I just got it.  It was tricky to figure this out...I don't use IB much so I had trouble seeing that this was possible.  Programatically, you have to create a segmented control in bar style, add that as a custom view to a UIBarButtonItem, then add that to a UIToolbar.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I'd suggest learning / getting used to using IB more, as it can save a lot of time and make things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying a UISegmentedControl?  You can set it up so that only one of the segments is "pressed" at a time.

Comment: I thought about that but I need this to be in the toolbar and segmented controls can't be resized.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in objc in real time

1. Create an array of stirings with your choices for radio button
2. create and put your UISegmentedControl into a UIBarButtonItem.
3. add that UIBarButtonItem to your navigationItem

worked for me. Code is below

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

// Uncomment this part if you need to do something when ratio state is selected. Also paste the function at the end of this post somewhere in your class.
// [segmentedControl addTarget:self   action:@selector(pickOne:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UIBarButtonItem *bbi= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
[segmentedControl release];


/* 
//and paste this function somethere in your class. It prints the label in debug terminal
- (void) pickOne:(id)sender{
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
NSLog(@"%@", [segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex: [segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]]);
} 
*/
```

I used some code from this (not mine) post http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/here-is-how-you-use-the-segmented-control-uisegmentedcontrol/129/